# How to retrieve Longitude and Latitude from CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-location

I have this code where I'm able to save Latitude and Longitude taken from a Map View coordinate. When the application starts up, I would like to retrieve those coordinates. I do notice, however that when I try to retrieve it, I get a lot of other information than what I want.

I retrieve it using this method, and print it on the console:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "GeoData")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do
    {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0 {
            print(results)
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //ERROR    
    }
```

But when I do, I get this:

```
 [<GeoData: 0x6000002876c0> (entity: GeoData; id: 0xd0000000014c0000 <x-coredata://1BDB903D-6F82-404A-A381-832E7932F832/GeoData/p83> ; data: {
    myLastLocation = nil;
    myLatitude = "24.16935894001965";
    myLongitude = "120.9677266312395";
})]
```

How can I retrieve the data again and just get the real value for myLatitude and myLongitude?

EDIT:

This is how I save it:

```
       if longPress.state == .ended 
       { 
        let touchLocation = longPress.location(in: mapView)
        let coordinate = mapView.convert(touchLocation, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        let newLocation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "GeoData", into: context)
        newLocation.setValue(coordinate.latitude  as Double, forKey: "myLatitude")
        newLocation.setValue(coordinate.longitude as Double, forKey: "myLongitude")
        do
        {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch
        {
            //ERROR
        }
       }
```

Comment: Have you tried using let results = try context.fetch(request) as <YOUR LOACTION MODEL> and then results.myLatitude and results.myLongitude?

Comment: You mean like let results = try context.fetch(request) as! Double ? It produced a "Cast from [Any] to unrelated type 'Double' always fails"

Comment: Whats your model class name for storing location related data?

Comment: I'm not sure about model class name. I didn't set it, I think. I'll add in the way I save it.

Comment: You should also add the code for storing location data in your question.

Comment: I added the code on how I stored it in the edit...

Comment: Please check my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your updated question:

You just need to declare your NSFetchRequest with correct type.
I pick up some statements from my code (Brand is a model in my project).

```
....
    let brandRequest = NSFetchRequest<Brand>(entityName: "Brand")

    do {
                let matches = try mycontext.fetch(brandRequest)
                return matches
            }catch let error as NSError {
                ...
            }
```

In this case, the matches you return is an array of "Brand" object.

And, if your data model has many attributes and you just need the longitude and latitude, you can try [NSFetchRequest.propertiesToFetch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506851-propertiestofetch). That's my first answer meant..

Comment: could you elaborate on how to use? I'm still trying to learn this.

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch like

```
    do
    {
        let results = try context.fetch(request) as! GeoData

        if results.count > 0 {
            print("\(results.myLatitude)) & \(results.myLongitude)")
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //ERROR    
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I get a Cast from [Any] to unrealted type 'GeoData always fails' on the fetch line and a Value type of 'GeoData' has no member 'count' on the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "GeoData")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do
    {
        let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
        if results.count > 0 {
            for result in results {
                if let latitude = result.value(forKey: "myLatitude") as? Double {
                    print(latitude)
                }
                if let longitude = result.value(forKey: "myLongitude") as? Double {
                    print(longitude)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //ERROR
    }
```

This one correctly prints out the latitude and longitude without the extra info.

```
19.7440716117355
129.099291435423
```